# I can not access my local PhpMyAdmin control panel

Tags: phpmyadmin, user-access

I have created a local WordPress (WP) website on my computer using the limited edition of DesktopServer. I then used FileZilla to download the WP files along with the associated database. Now I cannot access the local PhpMyAdmin control panel, anymore.
I used to access the control panel by clicking on the ‘Sites’ box in one of the DesktopServer screens (below)

[image]
Now, when I click on the same ‘Sites’ box, I am taken directly to my website (and, I don’t even know if it is my live site or a local copy).

I will appreciate any help that would show me how to access my local PhpMyAdmin control panel.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

http://localhost/phpmyadmin/

The manual says::

DesktopServer comes with PHPMyAdmin which allows you to manage your MySQL databases. You can access this tool two ways.

Open DesktopServer

In the left bottom corner is a [ Sites ] button, click it. This will open a page in your default browser, at the top is a menu item called "Tools". Click the Tools menu item and a list with the link to PHPMyAdmin - MySQL Administration.

or

Open your favorite browser and visit: http://localhost/phpmyadmin/